# Racket implementation of car, cdr, etc

Tags: lisp, racket, procedure

I want to create own implementation of such interface with following procedures :

```
(define (cons a b)...)
(define (pair? p) ... )
(define (car p) ...)
(define (cdr p) ...)
(define null ... )
(define (null? p) ... )
```

Pair and other functions has to be represented as returned procedures.
I started with:

```
(define (cons a b)
  (lambda (m) (m a b)))

(define (car p)
  (p (lambda (x y) x)))
  
(define (cdr p)
  (p (lambda (x y) y)))
```

And I'm stuck with:

```
(define (pair? p) ... )
(define null ... )
(define (null? p) ... )
```

Comment: Is this homework? What's your understanding of your `cons`, `car`, and `cdr`? How do they work?

Comment: This looks like some sort of highly academic Church encoding sort of mechanism that is very much *not* the typical way this would be done in Lisp. If that's correct, it should definitely be mentioned in the question